# written initial value (boundary condtions) to the results (.fil) file in an Abaqus/Standard analysis

Tags: abaqus

Set

```
*node file, frequency=1
U, COORD
*El file, frequency=1
S, COORD
```

In abaqus will create **.fil** document. It includes the last increment of each step.
However the **.fil** document didn't contain the initial value (which you can say the boundary conditions). Is there any way to do that by adding some words in **.inp** file.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this for Abaqus/Standard or Explicit? And if you are using a `*FILE OUTPUT` keyword, what does it look like?

Comment: @brady It is Abaqus/Standard. It creates .fil file